# Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage /Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, fatal-error

I'm trying to get all configurable attributes of a configurable product.

`$product_attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product)`

So far it worked properly, but suddenly it showed an error message

`Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage /Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php` and I have no idea of what's going on.

I tried to debug and in `Configurable.php` line `276`, `$this->getConfigurableAttributes($product)` returns 3 attributes but the first one doesn't belong to the product

And line `283`, `$attribute->getProductAttribute()` returns null, therefore, `$attribute->getProductAttribute()->getId()` caused the problem, crashed the app.

If anyone suffered this issue, please tell me what's going on. Any help will always be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662721/1974153

It's because I'm running multi websites on Magento, product A belongs to both site 1 and site 2.

In site 1, A has 1 attributes, in site 2 A has 2 other attributes. Then it caused the problem. I will try to get attributes that available in the current site only. Hope it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error. The problem was that the attributes defined in

```
$product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
```

was not part of the attribute set defined in

```
$product->setAttributeSetId(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getDefaultAttributeSetId())
```

Adding the attribute to the attribute set solved the problem for me.